# Metrics (Eclipse plugin) do not show

Tags: java, android, eclipse, plugins, metrics

I am writing here since I am experiencing a strange issue with METRICS plugin for Eclipse.

I am using Eclipse bundled with the latest Android Developer Tools version.

The problem is that, once I enable Metrics for my project, in the bottom right corner it shows that calculation of the metrics are being done.

But, as soon as it finished with all the calculations, the Metrics window shows:

"No metrics available for selection. To calculate and display metrics:

1) ensure you are in a java perspective using the package explorer
2) select a project and enable the metrics from its context menu
3) perform a full rebuil on the project"

Also the progress bar of the calculation seems to be empty (look for the red arrows) and the "temporarily pause all calculation" is active (blue arrow), as you can see in this screenshot of mine:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKz4d.png

I've tried enabling and disabling the Metrics many times, and also doing a full rebuild on the project didn't work.

The strange thing is that on my notebook it works perfectly fine, but on my desktop Metrics behaves like this and does not want to show (or calculate?!) the info I need.

Anyone can help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was then able to solve the issue by myslef simply removing and adding again the plugin in Eclipse.

Hope this proves to be useful to other people in the future!

Answer (score 0):

Try it: open Java Browsing perspective and search for “Metrics->Enable” option, after you can open the java perspective and open metrics view.